# Surface plot of data does not produce expected result

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to make a surface plot of [data.txt](http://textdump.net/raw/5809/). I use the following code as a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot3[surf, mesh/ordering = y varies] table {data.txt};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This code produces the following result:

[image: Observed result]

Using the same data in Matlab gives me the following surface plot, so this is the expected result.

[image: Expected result]

I have searched quite a bit, but I just cannot find out what is wrong. I expect some sort of incorrect indexing.

Comment: Something went wrong with your data export, the `data.txt` file you posted doesn't correspond to the data shown in your second plot. For example, take a look at the point at `(4,14)`: in your `data.txt` file, it has a value of `0.85`, but in the plot it's almost zero.

Comment: You are right, I was too focused on the LaTeX code and did not see the error in my data file. My apologies. I fixed it now.

Comment: Could you link to the new `data.txt` file?

Comment: Since it was only some example data, I fixed the issue and went on to use my real data. I do not have the new `data.txt` file anymore.

Comment: Ah, I see, I thought you had fixed the file and still had some issue with the plot. If the issue is resolved, perhaps it would be best to close this question?

Comment: Problem was caused by an incorrect data file.

Comment: Makes sense. So the problem itself went away by fixing the `data.txt` file. I do not know how to close a question.